# Digest in saml 2.0 for single sign on

Tags: saml

I am using saml2.0 for sinlgle sign on(SSO). In all the examples I have seen in the internet, there is a tag in the response-digest. What is this digest? Is this necessary even when the connection is https?

Comment: I am also going through the same problem. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when using SAML 2.0 and signed messages (HTTP Post requires digitally signed Responses), the DigestMethod and DigestValue are *required* and must be generated/validated per the XML Signature specification using Transform: Enveloped Signatures. If you don't properly sign/validate the message, what's to stop an attacker from intercepting the message and modifying its contents? SSL only protects the message in transit, not the contents of the message itself.

Comment: you have said 'SSL only protects the message in transit, not the contents of the message itself. ' then how will some third person be able to intercept it. He will not be able to make out anything unless he knows the shared secret key between the two parties, exchanged during ssl handshake.

Comment: Using TamperData or something similar it is trivial to grab a message and modify it and your site would never know.

Comment: one question - how does tamper data modify the the https packets.

Comment: What I have come to know about tamper data is that you can modify the data(post parameters) before the encryption is applied to it. But in SAML 2.0 you use the get request to send to pass on data which cannot be edited by Tamper Data.

Comment: The SAML2 WebSSO Post Profile does not allow the SAML Response to be sent via a GET request. It specifies POST or Artifact (See Sect 2 in the SAML 2.0 Conformance pdf (docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-conformance-2.0-os.pdf). Regardless, the spec says you must sign the Response when using WebSSO post Profile so I'm not sure why you continue down this path. HTTPS alone is not enough.

Comment: Yes I understand that https alone is not enough. But right now I am sending the "signed" saml "signed" request and signed response via GET. Since you redirect the user(from SP to IDP and vice versa) how will you be able to use POST(redirect can supports GET) ?

Comment: You can still send the AuthnRequest to IDP via HTTP-Redirect (aka GET), however, the Response must come back to SP via POST or Artifact.

Comment: No. The IDP sends the response via redirect(get). The SP checks if the <Response> is signed and that is not tampered. If authenticated, the user is forwarded to the respective service.

Comment: If the IDP is using Redirect, then it is not compliant with SAML2 POST Profile. Go read my previous messages. You can start a new thread with a new question but this now off topic.